# Hiding OK button for jAlert in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I wanted to show a jquery alert box to user, which will just show a message for few seconds and hides automatically.

This alert should not have any buttons for the user to select. After it hides, i should redirect the user to another page.

I can see things like this in modal dialogs. But i need it in jalert. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've yet to see a single case where blocking *everything* else for a few seconds, without option to shorten it, is good for user experience... what's wrong with clicking OK and being redirected earlier?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal

Lots of other options available:
http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+modal+dialog

Comment: Thanks for ur help. But as i mentioned in the question, i want to do it in jalert. Not with modal dialogs.